# Is range based for loop and normal index for loop are same in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, reverse

So i used a code to to reverse array something like this

```
for(vector<int> i:matrix)reverse(i.begin(),i.end());
```

but the output of this is not a reversed array at all, but when i does the same thing with index based loop it worked flawlessly

```
for(int i{0};i < matrix.size();i++)
{
    reverse(matrix[i].begin(),matrix[i].end());
}
```

Why is this haappening?

So i used the above to rotate the row of matrix, but they didn't worked even though i defined a custom reverse function to reverse a array then also it doesn't worked

Comment: `for(vector<int>& i:matrix)` -> You should pass by reference.

Comment: Because you are reversing **copies** of your vectors, make `i` a reference, `for(vector<int> i&:matrix)reverse(i.begin(),i.end());` so it refers to the vectors in the original matrix.

Comment: Because it works like `for(int x{0};x < matrix.size();x++) { vector<int> i = matrix[x]; reverse(i.begin(), i.end()); }`